# AVPlayerViewController fullscreen issues constraint warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to create an `UIViewController` with some labels and a movie in the middle of the screen. For the movie, I am using `AVPlayerViewController` but, whenever I click on its fullscreen button, I receive several constraint warnings even if I create the `AVPLayerViewController` from code, using `CGRect` for defining its bounds or if I embed it in a ContainerView using storyboard.

This is the code I am using when I don't rely in storyboard:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video_1" ofType:@"3gp"];


NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];


AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:movieURL];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;


[self addChildViewController:playerViewController];


[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];


playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 640, 480);


[player play];
```

Does anyone know how to fix the constraint issues?

Thank you